# Spring Integration: poller with fixedDelay for the whole flow execution

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In my integration flow I use JdbcPollingChannelAdapter to deliver list of entity keys, process those entities and set the time window for the next sql query to next iteration (based on last modification time of entities).
In case of processing delay or processing errors this next iteration shouldn't happen and MessageSource should wait until current flow execution succeeds or timeout happens. So at each time moment max. one list of keys should be processed.

Is there elegant way to set Pollers.fixedDelay(...) not for MessageSource but for whole flow execution so that next flow execution will be started after current is complited?

```
    @Test
    public void testDelayedExecutionSequence() {
    final Queue<List<Integer>> inQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    MessageSource<List<Integer>> inMs = new AbstractMessageSource<List<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public String getComponentType() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doReceive() {
            return inQueue.poll();
        }
    };

    final int messagesPerStep = 100;
    final int maxIterations = 10;
    for(int iteration = 1, from=1, to=messagesPerStep; iteration <= maxIterations; iteration++, from += messagesPerStep, to += messagesPerStep) {
        System.out.println(String.format("add list from=%d, to=%d", from, to));
        inQueue.add(IntStream.rangeClosed(from, to).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    final AtomicInteger amqpSendCounter = new AtomicInteger();
    final AtomicInteger iterationCounter = new AtomicInteger();
    final List<Integer> resultSequence = new ArrayList();

    IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(inMs, c->c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(50).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .split()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)))
            .<Integer, Integer>transform(p -> {
            if(p == 405) {
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            return p;})             
            .handle((p, h) -> {amqpSendCounter.incrementAndGet(); return p;})
            .aggregate()
            .log(l -> "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! after agregate(): "+l)
            .<List<Integer>>handle(m -> {iterationCounter.incrementAndGet();
                Integer firstIntInList = ((List<Integer>)m.getPayload()).get(0);
                resultSequence.add(firstIntInList / 100);
            })
            .get();

    IntegrationFlowRegistration registration = this.flowContext.registration(integrationFlow).register();

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

    assertThat(iterationCounter.get()).as("iterationCounter.get").isEqualTo(maxIterations);
    assertThat(resultSequence).as("result sequence").isEqualTo(IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 9).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look into the [Conditional polling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers) and don’t let to call `receive()` until some state is changed. The `PollSkipAdvice` should b a good choice for you.